# Side-navbar on click color change

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap 4 side navbar. Bootstrap have a default color for onclick/active links . How to change it’s default color.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question, at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use the CSS `:active` tag to your selector then add `color:` your color `;` Example: `a:active{ color:blue; }`.